# How do I perform index operations in Eigen?

Tags: c++, indexing, eigen

I need to give a section of my code an index into an object that is stored as an `Eigen::Array` type. I don't have the luxury of extending Eigen's functionality to that section of code, nor can I pass it a pointer. I need an *index* representing the location of a matched value in the array.

So suppose I have an `Eigen::Array` object like this:

```
Eigen::Array<int,5,1> mat;
mat << 0, 0, 1, 0, 1;
```

Now I would like to find the first index of an element in the above matrix which compares equal to some condition (say, they compare equal to *true*).

So for the above input I would like an output of `2`. I would also accept an output of `4` as I'm not particularly fussed about order (if the option exists to specify a search direction that would be good, but not essential).

```
std::size_t const index = FindIndex(mat);
assert(index == 2 || index == 5); // please don't fail!
```

I know that I can just loop through the array and achieve this manually via a counter, but that somewhat misses the point of `Eigen`. Is there a way of achieving this using `Eigen`'s inbuilt features (*other* than `unaryExpr`?

Comment: `Eigen::Array<int,5,1> mat();` is a function declaration

Comment: @MattMcNabb how do you figure?

Comment: `*name-of-type* *identifier* ();` means "declare function called *identifier*, taking no arguments and returning a value of type *name-of-type*". [See here](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+a%28%29%3B)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I see. Better now?

Answer (score 0):

No. There's nothing I can see that you can use for this.

You can find out how many non-zero values there are:

```
std::size_t const numNonZero = (mat != 0).count();
assert(numNonZero == 2);
```